# Get last part of url using a regex

Tags: java, regex, solr

How do I get the last part of the a URL using a regex, here is my URL, I want the segmeent between the last forward slash and the #

```
http://mycompany.com/test/id/1234#this
```

So I only want to get `1234`.

I have the following but is not removing the '#this'

```
".*/(.*)(#|$)",
```

I need this while indexing data so don't want to use the URL class.

Comment: Does it have to be a regex?  Why not use String methods, like substring, lastIndexOf, etc?

Comment: @Jim there is even better than that in the JDK itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about:

```
".*/([^/#]*)(#.*|$)"
```

Comment: Will fail if there is any query string in there.

Answer (score 5):

Just use `URI`:

```
final URI uri = URI.create(yourInput);
final String path = uri.getPath();
path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); // will return what you want
```

Will also take care of URIs with query strings etc. In any event, when having to extract any part from a URL (which *is* a URI), using a regex is not what you want: `URI` can handle it all for you, at a much lower cost -- since it has a dedicated parser.

Demo code using, in addition, Guava's `Optional` to detect the case where the URI has no path component:

```
public static void main(final String... args) {
    final String url = "http://mycompany.com/test/id/1234#this";
    final URI uri = URI.create(url);
    final String path = Optional.fromNullable(uri.getPath()).or("/");
    System.out.println(path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition to what [@jtahlborn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/552759/jtahlborn) answer to include query string:

```
".*/([^/#|?]*)(#.*|$)"
```